# How to hide tooltip displayed in AG Grid Columns tool panel?

Tags: vuejs2, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I am adding a header tooltip for each of the headers in AG Grid.
As it also has a column selection menu as well as a Filter Tool Panel, the same headers are displayed in that pop-up menu and they also get the same tooltip applied to the headers.

I don't want the tooltip to be displayed over the headers in the columns selection menu or in the Filter Tool Panel but want them on the Grid Headers, How can I achieve that?

Filter Tool Panel Sandbox link: https://plnkr.co/edit/eGAErj1C7eqsH3Dr?open=main.js

`columnDefs: [{ field: 'athlete', headerTooltip: "Header tooltip getting displayed in Filter Tool Panel as well" }]`

Steps to reproduce the issue in the sandbox:

1. Hover on the 'Athlete' column header in the Grid. (You'll see a tooltip).
2. Open the Filter Tool Panel if not already, and hover over the same 'Athlete' column header. (You'll see the same tooltip there as well).

Expected behavior:

- Hovering over the column header in the Filter Tool Panel should not show the tooltip.

Column Selector Panel Sandbox link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/t8NTKOa0ubvB7JUo?open=main.js

It has a similar issue as the Filter Tool Panel.

Ag Grid Version: 27.3.0

Comment: The probability of getting help without showing some code is almost `null`. Ideally you should present a *runnable* [mcve]. Use a [SO] snippet, codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.